# Loading polylines in the background on google maps api v2 for android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have to display polylines to show different areas on the google map. I am reading the coordinates for polylines from the local files and it is taking too much time to read and then load maps with all boundary marked.

What I want to do is - load the map first and then add polylines in the background so that use doesn't have to wait to see the map.

Is there anyway to take actions such as draw polylines on google map in the background after map is loaded?

Thanks

Comment: all map object need to be drawn on the UI thread

Comment: You can access from background thread main UI thread and draw your polylines.

Comment: @Anatol I am facing same problem can you describe how it can be done ?